# Cannot open connection

Tags: hibernate, glassfish-3

If my web application run in glassfish v2 it run correctly but if I deploy the same application in glassfish v3 it throws " ***org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection "*** exception

please help.

In my server Log file id shows ----->

> WARNING: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001 SEVERE: No suitable driver
>   found for jdbc:mysql://ntpl-bdc:3306/macs_pharma SEVERE: Cannot open
>   connection org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot
>   open connection
>           at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:99)
>           at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
>           at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
>           at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
>           at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
>           at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1596)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:717)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2294)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2172)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2167)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:448)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
>           at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1258)
>           at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
>           at com.access.DataReturn.getMRs(DataReturn.java:31)
>           at webService.Pharma.getMRNames(Pharma.java:30)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.glassfish.webservices.InstanceResolverImpl$1.invoke(InstanceResolverImpl.java:137)
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:146)
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:257)
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:95)
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:629)
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.*doRun(Fiber.java:588)
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573)
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470)
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:112)
>           at org.glassfish.webservices.MonitoringPipe.process(MonitoringPipe.java:138)
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:115)
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.*_doRun(Fiber.java:629)
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.*doRun(Fiber.java:588)
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573)
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470)
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:112)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.processRequest(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:195)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.process(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:127)
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:115)
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.*_doRun(Fiber.java:629)
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:588)
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573)
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470)
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:295)
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:515)
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:285)
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:143)
>           at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:147)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:mysql://ntpl-bdc:3306/macs_pharma
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
>           at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
>           at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
>           ... 73 more

Comment: Are there other exceptions listed as cause of this one in your log? Like not being able to find the jdbc driver class for your db engine?

Comment: thanks for response...But if I use normal JDBC connection it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your JDBC driver jar needs to be in `${GLASSFISH_INSTALL}/glassfish/lib`.